# webview not showing hyperlinks

Tags: android, webview

I have a String: **myFullString** which looks like:

```
<html>
<body style="background-color: transparent; margin-top:75px; padding:0px;"> 
<style type="text/css"> 
p {margin-left:40px; margin-right:40px; margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px; } 
</style> <p> 
<font face="helvetica" size=8 color=white> 
<b>  Heading 
</b></font> 
<font face="helvetica" size=6> <br/> <br/>  
<br/> Address Line 1 
<br/> Address Line 2 <br/> 
<br/> Tel: PhoneNumber 
<br/> Fax: Fax No <br/> 
<br/> <br/><br/>
</font></p> 
</body></html>
```

I want the phone numbers and/or link if any to appear as clickable/hi lighted. So I wrote the following code:

```
        Spannable sp = new SpannableString(myFullString.toString());
        Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
        final String html = Html.toHtml(sp) ;
        mWebView.setClickable(true);
        mWebView.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I get the following result:
[image: hyperlink exists but it shows the whole file]

In this webview, the texts are hyperlinked but we are able to see the tags.

I also tried using the following code:

```
Spannable sp = new SpannableString(myFullString.toString());
Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sp.toString(),"text/html", "utf-8", "about:blank");
```

But it's giving the following output:

[image: loadDataWithBaseURL]

It shows the correct text font, but does not link the texts.

How do I modify my code such that the links are shown and it won't show the tags?
The webview contents are created dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was not able to find an easier way...

I did some thing like this for every line which was to be shown in the webpage:

```
            String str=mWebFileArray [i].toString();
            if(str.contains("<!- ")){
                str.replace("<!- ", "<!-- ").replace(" ->", " -->");
            }else{
                Spannable sp = new SpannableString(str);
                Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
                str = Html.toHtml(sp) ;
            }
            myArray.add(str);
```

now, it links the valid text....